# How to find more information about the file descriptor?

Tags: python, c, file-descriptor

I am trying to debug a process that hangs, the output of  strace for the process id has last line :
 `recvfrom(9,  <detached ...>`
From this what I understand that the process is waiting on the socket.

But I don't know which or what kind of socket is this. How can I discover more about this ? does the file descriptor 9 will give me more information ? How can I use this file discover to know more about what it is waiting for ?

its a python process, running in linux.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Is that Python or C? Why added both tags?

Comment: Its a python process running in linux. Updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using `strace` I assume you are on Linux and you know the process id. In that case you can find a lot of info in `/proc`. Here is an example of what to do.

Do `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd`. There will be an entry corresponding to the fd you are interested in and that fd should be a socket as such:

```
$ ls -l /proc/3311/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 alanau alanau 64 Sep 24 20:37 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 alanau alanau 64 Sep 24 20:37 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 alanau alanau 64 Sep 24 20:37 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 alanau alanau 64 Sep 24 20:37 3 -> socket:[23182]
```

In the above example, `3` is the socket of interest. The number after `socket` is the inode number, `23182` in this case.

Now look in the file `/proc/net/tcp` to find that inode:

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcp | grep 23182
   2: 0F02000A:C43B 8EDC3AD8:0050 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 **23182** 1 0000000000000000 23 0 0 10 -1
```

The first line of `/proc/net/tcp` tells you what each field represents:

```
 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
```

So in this example, the remote address is `8EDC3AD8:0050`. That's the ip_addres:port_number in hex and network byte ordering. If you convert that to decimal it is `216.58.220.142:80`.

Which tells you it is in fact a TCP connection to port 80 of google.com!

If you don't find the inode number in `/proc/net/tcp` then try the other protocols in the directory, probably `/proc/net/udp`.

Answer (score 1):

Look earlier in the `strace` output for when the file descriptor was returned from `open()` (or perhaps `socket()`), there you'll see the additional arguments used in the call.